# not getting proper string from xml parsing

Tags: objective-c, string, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an xml which has data inbetween the tags like "S |nºconta|".I'm saving this as follows

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {     
foundText = (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

Where `foundText` is `NSString`. But i'm not getting the complete data as "S |nºconta|" instead i'm getting just "nºconta|" where "S |" characters are removed.

This is the xmlversion: "".
S |nºconta|.
"Details" is the tag name.Whenever "Details" is encountered i'm taking this to NSMutableString *foundText as given above and adding this back to NSMutableArray.But when it encounters S |nºconta| foundText will have only "nºconta|" leaving "|S"

Comment: Can you provided more information? E.g.: Can you show (a fragment of) the XML? What is the encoding of the XML? Is just `foundText` wrong or also `foundCharacters`? Edit your question to add the details.

Comment: Sorry foundText is NSMutableString.This is the xmlversion: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>".<Details>S |nºconta|</Details>."Details" is the tag name.Whenever "Details" is encountered i'm taking this to NSMutableString *foundText as given above and adding this back to NSMutableArray.But when it encounters S |nºconta| foundText will have only "nºconta|" leaving "|S"

Comment: In the question you state `foundText` is an `NSMutableArray`, in your above comment that it is an `NSMutableString`... The method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` returns an `NSString *` and the cast  you use won't change that. You need to put into the question (not in a comment, edit the question) what you are really doing or else people can really only guess what your problem might be. In case it helps: try `NSLog()`'ing `foundCharacters` - that will well you if the issue is in the XML parsing or with what you do with the result of the parse.