# Not getting expected string after parsing with NSXMLParser

Tags: string, cocoa

I'm parsing an xml which has data in between the tags like "S |nºconta|".I'm saving this as follows

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {     
foundText = (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

Where `foundText` is `NSMutableString`. But i'm not getting the complete data as "S |nºconta|" instead i'm getting just "nºconta|" where "S |" characters are removed.

Where in xml `<Details>S |nºconta|</Details>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [not getting proper string from xml parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950788/not-getting-proper-string-from-xml-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you have illegal characters in the XML - anything outside the regular ASCII range (0-127) should be escaped using a &#xx; or an equivalent named entity.

Comment: Sorry,I didnt understand...what should i do??

Comment: You should confirm that your document really is UTF-8 encoded, not just claims to be.

Comment: You do know, that foundCharacters: will potentially get called multiple times for the one element don't you?  Apple does not guarantee to call you with just one chunk of text.  

    The parser object may send the delegate several parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an element. Because string may be only part of the total character content for the current element, you should append it to the current accumulation of characters until the element changes.

Comment: Can you please share me the chunk of code what should i do for getting the proper string as i'm getting "nºconta|" instead of "S |nºconta|".I'm trying to display the string using NSLog as you suggested which shows the same "nºconta|" instead of "S| nºconta|" .It'll help me a lot.Thanks in advance

Comment: You should upload the actual data file you are parsing somewhere - copy/pasting text here is insufficient as it will mask any file encoding problems.  And show *your* code.  Without wanting to sound too rude, I can't do your homework for you...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, it works just fine.

```
@implementation XMLDELEGATE
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"didStartElement(%@)",elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"didEndElement(%@)",elementName);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"foundCharacters(%@)",string);
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    static const unsigned char bytes[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Details>S |nºconta|</Details>";
    NSXMLParser *p;
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)-1];

    p = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:d];
    NSLog(@"data=%@",d);
    p.delegate = [XMLDELEGATE new];
    [p parse];
}

@end
```

outputs this:

```
2014-03-01 15:35:07.272 xmlp2[35923:303] data=<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e302220 656e636f 64696e67 3d225554 462d3822 3f3e3c44 65746169 6c733e53 207c6ec2 ba636f6e 74617c3c 2f446574 61696c73 3e>
2014-03-01 15:35:07.273 xmlp2[35923:303] didStartElement(Details)
2014-03-01 15:35:07.273 xmlp2[35923:303] foundCharacters(S |n)
2014-03-01 15:35:07.273 xmlp2[35923:303] foundCharacters(ºconta|)
2014-03-01 15:35:07.273 xmlp2[35923:303] didEndElement(Details)
```

As I said in my other answer, you are probably not paying attention to the multiple calls to foundCharacters.  It is your responsibility, as delegate, to glue the multiple chunks of string data together in each element (and !CDATA if that happens)